# How to display array property with php

Tags: php

I have record array like this :

```
object(stdClass)#746 (3) {
  ["error_code"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["error_desc"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["result"]=>
  object(stdClass)#747 (7) {
    ["id_smt"]=>
    string(5) "20151"
    ["nm_sms"]=>
    string(7) "Adriene"
  }
}
```

I would like to have an output from id_smt and nm_sms. I tried to create like this :

```
foreach ($recordset->result as $dt) {
  echo $dt->id_smt;
}
```

But it's not working, and the error message :

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Just write `echo $dt;` you already loop through the entire object!

Comment: it's working, but how can i display one of the result. Can you tell me ?

Comment: If you only want to print a single property you don't need to use a loop just do: `echo $recordset->result->id_smt;`